# Using mapStateToProps and state with connect() in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using Redux-Form & am trying to get the values from that form. The [documentation](https://redux-form.com/6.0.1/docs/api/selectors.md/) suggests that the way to use `getFormValues()` is as such:

```
MyComponent = connect(
  state => ({
    values: getFormValues('myForm')(state),
  })
)(MyComponent)
```

In my component, I am currently using `connect` with `mapStateToProps` in my component. But how can I use both of these together? My current code (that doesn't work, as the personFormValues is `undefined`), is as such:

```
export default reduxForm({
  form: 'personsForm'
})(connect(mapStateToProps, state => ({
  personFormValues: getFormValues('personsForm')(state)
}))(PersonsForm));
```

I have also tried:

```
export default reduxForm({
  form: 'personsForm'
})(connect(state => ({
  personFormValues: getFormValues('personsForm')(state),
  mapStateToProps
}))(PersonsForm));
```

and

```
export default reduxForm({
  form: 'personsForm'
})(connect(state => ({
  personFormValues: getFormValues('personsForm')(state),
}), mapStateToProps)(PersonsForm));
```

and

```
export default reduxForm({
  form: 'personsForm'
})(connect(state => ({
  personFormValues: getFormValues('personsForm')(state),
  personsForm: state.form.personsForm
}))(PersonsForm));
```

In the latter instance, personsForm and personFormValues returns as undefined.

What is the correct way to use both with `connect`?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. I just added it into the `mapStateToProps` method like so:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  personsForm: state.form.personsForm,
  values: getFormValues('personsForm')(state)
});
```